Angular multilanguage routing
I'm making my angular SSR app support multilanguage, I've followed this tutorial https://docs.angular.lat/guide/i18n
I'm facing the issue that now I have to type in mydomain.com/en to be able to access my website. And mydomain.com/fr to access the fr version.
How can I make the english version be supported on mydomain.com without the /en?
Thanks!
